# Apache zepplin spark job runs faster than spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Am wondering if there is any reason why the spark job I wrote in Zepplin paragraph executes much faster than running spark-submit myself?

I basically use the same configuration (executors, memory) in Zepplin and spark-submit but there is so much significant difference in execution time.

Both are running on the same standalone spark cluster.

What can explain this difference ?

Comment: What's the job's code?

Comment: @T.Gawęda I don't think it's the code, it's probably because am using zepplin spark context(sc), sqlContext that may differ from my spark conf

Comment: Are you accounting for startup/shutdown time? I imagine the Zeppelin instance is already running so there is no startup time. If you haven't already try using internal Scala timing

Answer (score 1):

There are two things I can think of which might result in this.

1. When using zappelin you already have a spark context which you are probably using. When you do a spark-submit you create a new one which takes some time.
2. Even if your timing discounts the spark context (e.g. you only count the time for the actual job), in zappelin you probably do some other jobs before the current one. These can cause various caching to occur. Some examples include:

   - The OS/hadoop might cache files you are reading because you read them in a previous cell
   - You might be doing a shuffle you did before on some RDD so it is cached
   - You might have an explicit cache
   - You might have a dataframe you are using for join already partitioned correctly in a previous cell
   - the list goes on...

Comment: Yea, I thought almost about all those possibilities but it doesn't explain why writing to db (approx. 148million records) is taken significantly lesser time than running in spark-submit. Same code but written as different paragraphs in Zepplin. I could see how long each tasks takes in Spark UI.

Comment: When you do your profiling, you can make sure you load every external element outside the profiling. For example, in your program call spark.range(100).show() which would load the spark context, then wrap a timer around the job itself. In zepplin on the other hand, make sure to only run the relevant cell and nothing else and then compare. Given this you should be seeing the same performance. I assume of course you are using the same configuration for both tests.